# How do I view a LDB File on Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ios

I need help viewing a LDB file on Windows that I pulled from iOS. Any help is appreciated!

Picture of the files I am trying to open:

[image]

Here is a picture to the LDB files I am trying to access. These files were pulled from the Application UBER from an iPhone and uploaded to BlackLight Release v3.1

Comment: Are you Jailbroken?  This will be impossible without jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ can open this file and interpret it more or less correctly (you'll see some NUL values after each string but those can be ignored).

You will see a list of computer names who have opened the file and the level of access they had (usually all "Admin"):

[image: Screenshot of Notepad++ showing the contents of a .ldb file]

Answer (score -1):

Try iFunBox or iManager. It doesn't matter if you are jailbroken or not; but if you are are jailbroken you can WRITE as well as read.

If you are jailbroekn, try iFunBox or iManager on your PC. This will show you the LDB files and allow to read/write to them. If you are not jailbroken, then you will only be able to read/copy the files, but not modify them.

Comment: Hi Rookie, if I am just trying to read th LBD files, is it possible without the phone being jailbroken? And if so, what program would be best?
I do not need to modify them, just read the files.

Comment: Did you mean use iFunBox or iManager too if my phone isnt jailbroken?

Comment: You can read them as long as you have a program for that; iFunBox and iManager can only view the location and open it with a different program.